# Listening to multiple ports with TcpListener

Tags: c#, networking, tcp, ports

I need to listen to about 100 different ports via TCP. Looking at the TcpListener class in C#, it obviously listens on just one port. Does it make sense to create 100 different TcpListener instances each with their own port.

I am not seeing it as a clean solution but it seems like the only option.

Comment: A strange requirement but why not. Just make sure it is not an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341)

Comment: Basically, I have different sim cards sending data which all have the same IP so I cant listen on one port with different IPs (as usual). Instead I am setting different ports on the application from where the data is being sent so I can know which one it is.

Comment: Is there no way you can get your devices to send some sort of ID as part of it's message to you ? Ie identify by message and all go to one port ? That's what I have done when my multitude of devices are hiding behind NAT.

Comment: They send it the first time just to make an ACK. It is then up to you to continue the link. Should the IPs were not the same, I could link the IP with this unique ID. That is why I though about using different ports instead.

Comment: Can you clarify some more - ensure it's not an XY problem ? Do you write the software for the device or only have limited config options ?

Comment: I have limited config options. On other devices I dont have this problem since I write software for it and thus I send a unique id with each packet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you need 100 `TcpListener`s. The best is to put them in a list (initialised looping through a list of ports), and manage them as a single entity in a loop

Comment: Don't simply listen in a loop, learn to use either i) BeginAccept... or ii) Accept..Async, other performance.